# Absolute convergence and operations over series

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

I'm reading Conway's Complex Analysis book and on page 38 he said we can manipulate the power series because they are absolute convergent:

[image]

So which operations can I do in non-absolute convergent series $S$? can I do multiplication by a constant? the distributivity works? If $S$ is absolute convergent can I do some of these operations?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind absolutely converge is not the same as converge -- for a series $\sum a_n$ to absolutely converge, the series $ \sum |a_n| $ must converge. In other words, it must still converge, even if you made all the terms positive, rather than some positive and some negative.

However you don't always need to hold a sequence to such a high standard. In some cases it's fine if it converges without any higher standards. For example, it's straightforward to show that if $\lim_{n\to \infty} (a_1+...+a_n)$=L, then C $\lim_{n\to \infty} (a_1+...+a_n)$=C$L$. So multiplying by a constant works.

I recommend investigating which other properties hold (especially if you're taking real analysis, as this is the sort of thing you should be strong at.)

The main issue with conditionally convergent sequences is you can't rearrange the terms, or its value may change. You can search online to see examples of this.